# How to write Insert ignore or update for this Query?

Tags: mysql, procedure

I have a MYSQL Stored Procedure for merging the data between staging table and MST table.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `LDA_MERGE_TRACTOR_EQUPIMENT`()
BEGIN
    INSERT IGNORE
INTO Appian.LDA_CETARIS_TRACTOR_EQUIPMENT_MST(
    `Asset #`,
    `Fleet Code`,
    `Description`,
    `Asset Category`,
    `Asset Type`,
    `Asset Item`
)
SELECT
    `Asset #`,
    `Faleet Code`,
    `Description`,
    `Asset Category`,
    `Asset Type`,
    `Asset Item`
FROM
    Appian.LDA_CETARIS_TRACTOR_EQUIPMENT_STAGING stg
ORDER BY
    `Asset #`
ON DUPLICATE KEY
UPDATE
    `Fleet Code` = stg.`Fleet Code`,
    `Description` = stg.`Description`,
    `Asset Category`= stg.`Asset Category`,
    `Asset Type` = stg.`Asset Type`,
    `Asset Item` = stg.`Asset Item`;
END
```

`Asset #`,is the primary key of both tables. but I received error message:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 29

Line 29:     `Asset Item` = stg.`Asset Item`;
```

Can anyone help me? thanks!

Comment: Use VALUES() function, like `Fleet Code = VALUES(Fleet Code)` - i.e. update with the value which should be inserted if no duplicate detected.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define the `delimeter` like below,

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `LDA_MERGE_TRACTOR_EQUPIMENT`()
BEGIN
    INSERT IGNORE
INTO Appian.LDA_CETARIS_TRACTOR_EQUIPMENT_MST(
    `Asset #`,
    `Fleet Code`,
    `Description`,
    `Asset Category`,
    `Asset Type`,
    `Asset Item`
)
SELECT
    `Asset #`,
    `Faleet Code`,
    `Description`,
    `Asset Category`,
    `Asset Type`,
    `Asset Item`
FROM
    Appian.LDA_CETARIS_TRACTOR_EQUIPMENT_STAGING stg
ORDER BY
    `Asset #`
ON DUPLICATE KEY
UPDATE
    `Fleet Code` = stg.`Fleet Code`,
    `Description` = stg.`Description`,
    `Asset Category`= stg.`Asset Category`,
    `Asset Type` = stg.`Asset Type`,
    `Asset Item` = stg.`Asset Item`;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

For more info please visit [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stored-programs-defining.html).